# C# - Inheritance and interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Sorry for the bad title, but I didn't know how to entitle this in a good way.

Let the following interfaces :

```
interface IFoo
{
}

interface IBar
{
}
```

And the following classes :

```
class Base
{
}

class Derived1 : Base, IFoo, IBar
{
}

class Derived2 : Base, IFoo, IBar
{
}
```

I need to have a common type for `Derived1` and `Derived2` that has all the features of `Base`, `IFoo` and `IBar`. so that i can have instances of both `Derived1` and `Derived2` into the same collection and have access to the features of `Base`, `IFoo` and `IBar` without doing some reflexion black magic.

If `Base` was an interface, I would just have to create an interface requiring to implement `Base`, `IFoo` and `IBar`, but it's not the case.

I also do not want to have an intermediate inheritance between `Derived1` / `Derived2` and `Base` :

```
class Intermediate : Base, IFoo, IBar
{
}

class Derived1 : Intermediate
{
}

class Derived2 : Intermediate
{
}
```

Because I'm in the context of Unity and inheritance is to be avoided there more than anywhere.

Also I cannot modify `Base`.

I thought about having an `IBase` interface that requires all the features of `Base` and have an "intermediate" interface requiring to implement it too, i.e :

```
interface IIntermediate : IBase, IFoo, IBar
{
}

class Derived1 : Base, IIntermediate
{
}

class Derived2 : Base, IIntermediate
{
}
```

But I would have to copy all of the features of `Base` (and its parents) into `IBase` and `IBase` would also not be a `Base`. So that looks a bit dirty and might cause me problems I don't see yet.

I there a different way to acheive what I need to do other than the two possibilities mentionned above ? Thank you !

Comment: What exactly about Unity requires you to avoid inheritance? You're already inheriting from `Base`, it's unclear why an additional level of inheritance would be undesirable.

Comment: Could you please add the concrete types that you are *actually* wanting to derive from? What is `Base`?

Comment: Why can't you change `Base`?

Comment: Well `Base` is actually `MonoBehaviour`. I would like to avoid an extra level of inheritance, because when you declare a Unity "event" (such as Awake(), Update(), etc), you also have to manually call the parent one, if any. This is error prone and not nice to maintain.

Comment: So I see strong constraint for inheritance. If you want have an object that can refer to all derived class, make an interface that inherit all Interface except `Base` and use Tuple with the type parameter  of  `Base` and your new Interface, but both indicate to same object. It's just a relief not a strong solution.

Comment: @MazaherBazari You mean that I should manipulate my objects through a Tuple that references them as two different types, like a "composite reference", instead of referencing them using a single type ? I'll think about that, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Virus721 Yes. Use two parameter tuple and make it  reference  to your object.

Comment: I ended up using the "intermediate" interface solution I wrote, because while Mazaher Bazari's solution is intersting and works given the constraints I indicated, I also have other constraints which I did not indicate, such as using the "common type" I need as a generic parameter to a class that expects a T `where T : Base, IFoo, IBar` and not a `Tuple<Base, IFooBar>`. I could modify that latter class to work with a tuple, but I have the feeling that I will run into some trouble sooner or later. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a class with implicit operators to be able to get constructed and return all the desired types.

```
class MyBase : IFoo, IBar
{
    Base innerValue;
    public static implicit operator Base(MyBase value)
    {
        return value.innerValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyBase(Derived1 value)
    {
        return new MyBase(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator MyBase(Derived2 value)
    {
        return new MyBase(value);
    }

    public MyBase(Derived1 value)
    {
        innerValue = value;
    }
    public MyBase(Derived2 value)
    {
        innerValue = value;
    }
    // Implement IFoo and IBar based on innerValue calls
}
```

This would allow you to create an array like this:

```
MyBase[] myArray = new MyBase[] {new Derived1(), new Derived2()};
```

And you could still treat each instance as a Base:

```
Base B1 = myArray[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I won't be able to do that because I must make my derived classes inherit from the base one, directly or indirectly. Sorry for not mentionning it. And also that base class wrapper would have to know about its subclasses and be modified anytime I create a new derived classes. Thanks for taking the time to help anyway. :)

Comment: @Virus721 Your `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes would still be inheriting from Base just as you had coded. That's what allows MyBase's operators to automaticaly convert from `Derived1` to `Base` in the `MyBase` constructors.

Comment: Mmmhh true, I didn't understand properly. So I just make my derived classes inherit from the base one. The only difference is that the reference gets wrapped into this class so that they can be aded to the same collection ? I will try. I'll accept your answer cause it seems to answer the question, regardless of how it works for my real case. Thx

Comment: Seems to work nicely in my case ! I can probably improve maintainability using some generics.